# DateTimeImmutable first day of this year

Tags: php, date

I want to get the first day of this year, as in 2019/01/01.

Using this code:

```
new \DateTimeImmutable('first day of this year'));
```

But what I get is *2019/10/01*, it seems to return the first day of this month anyway?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: You format as `->format('Y-m-d')` but you say you are getting `2019/10//01` ?? Really

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm tired, I was trying to explain the problem, you get the point, it returns current month and not first day of the year. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of the vagaries of date string parsing, "first day of" only works with a month (see the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)). You can just use something like these instead:

```
echo (new \DateTimeImmutable('January 1'))->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
echo (new \DateTimeImmutable('first day of January'))->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
2019-01-01
2019-01-01
```

Note you can also write

```
echo (new \DateTimeImmutable('first day of january this year'))->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
```

although the "this year" part is superfluous as any date/time expression that doesn't explicitly mention a year will refer to the current one. That form of the expression is more useful in these cases:

```
echo (new \DateTimeImmutable('first day of january last year'))->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
echo (new \DateTimeImmutable('first day of january next year'))->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
2018-01-01
2020-01-01
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/8ZbUN)

Comment: This works! Thanks, I wonder why you have to specify Janaury like that..

Comment: This approach also works appending the 'this year' like this: `"first day of January this year"`

Comment: @Mathall if you mean with a capital `J`, you don't. What's important is just that `January` is the first month of the year, so the "first day of January" will be the first day of the year.

Comment: @Claudio good point, I've included a note about that (and also using "last year" and "next year" for good measure).